# Using ${StrTok} in NSI script

Tags: nsis, uninstallation, strtok

I have written a small NSI script to get substring, parsed for a comma :

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
${StrTok} 
OutFile abc.exe

Section "jj" main_section

SectionEnd 

Function .onInit

${StrTok} $0 "b,lah" "," "L" "0"

FunctionEnd
```

The above code works perfectly fine.
But when I tried to use the StrTok in an uninstall macro, it keeps giving me "Invalid command:{StrTok}" error.

Could someone please let me know :

1. How do I use the 'StrTok' in uninstall macro?
2. In the above snippet of code , why is the 2nd line required? What does it signify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first ${StrTok} creates the function and after that it calls the function. To use it in the uninstaller you must use ${UnStrTok}:

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
${StrTok}
${UnStrTok}

Section
  ${StrTok} ...
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
  ${UnStrTok} ...
SectionEnd
```

**Edit:**
Here is another example (Tested with NSIS v2.46):

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
${UnStrTok}

!macro Uninstall 
${UnStrTok} $1 "b,lah" "," "L" "0" ;
MessageBox mb_ok $1
Delete "$temp\un.exe"
!macroend
Section "Uninstall"
!insertmacro Uninstall
SectionEnd
Section "Install"
WriteUninstaller "$temp\un.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Using {UnStrTok} is also giving the same error. I want to use the UnStrTok in a macro ,and I am calling the macro from a Section.

Comment: Section "Uninstall"
  !insertmacro Uninstall
SectionEnd

!macro Uninstall
  ${UnStrTok} $1 "b,lah" "," "L" "0"  ;
!macroend

Comment: Could someone please post an example or suggest an alternative for StrTok?

Comment: If I use {UnStrTok}, in a small program, it works, but when I try it in a NSI script , whic has many other macros in it , it fails. The basic format of the script is same though

Comment: I get following error:

 $ {UnStrTok} "$1" "$0" "," "L" "0" (macro:FUNCTION_STRING_UnStrTok_Call:3)
 Push: $0
 Push: ,
 Push: L
 Push: 0
 Call must not be used with functions starting with "un." in the non-uninstall sections.
 Usage: Call function_name | [:label_name]
 Error in macro FUNCTION_STRING_UnStrTok_Call on macroline 10
 Error in macro Uninstall on macroline 16

Comment: The example I posted works and I don't know how to explain it any better. If you are going to complain about broken code at least edit your question with the new code...